# How often are tagged question counts updated?

Tags: support, tags

For example (at the time this question was asked), on [the /tags page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags), the Javascript tag shows: "1043 asked today, 5816 this week", while on [the /questions/tagged page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript?sort=newest&days=7), it cites "6,664 questions tagged this week"

Which count is more accurate, how often are the counts updated, and is this information available via the API?

Comment: Don't use code formatting for emphasis.

Comment: I'd prefer if my line breaks were kept for clarity.

Comment: There's a difference between "emphasis and clarity" and "too many line breaks". It's probably better to name those links; give me a moment.

Comment: Good point. I meant clarity.